# Hiding table in SAP Adobe Forms

Tags: adobe, abap, sap-basis, livecycle-designer, adobe-form

I am working on a project in Adobe Forms (Interactive Forms) in SAP ABAP, and I have a table that can contain data or not according to some Select statements. When it contains data the table will be printed out otherwise the table must be hidden. I have tried to do this by using FormCalc (and also JavaScript) in the form script and the code is as follows: (and it didn`t work)

```
'''
//form::ready

if( $.hasData == null) then
  $.presence = "hidden"
else $.presence = "visible"
endif
'''
```

If data came from Select statement the table is populated and otherwise it is not. The table is printed in both situations, so it is not an implementation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select JavaScript as script type and put following into `initialization` event of table element:

```
if(this.Row1.Cell1.rawValue == "")
{
   this.HeaderRow.presence = "hidden" ;
}
```

where `cell1` is a cell of data row of your table and `HeaderRow` is a header.

[image]